# Где можно найти текст  "Безоговорочной теории русского языка"

Tags: нормы-языка

Уважаемые господа! В мой адрес в последнее время приходят многочисленные пожелания ознакомиться с текстом моей безоговорочной теории русского языка. По этому поводу могу сказать следующее:

Да, текст "Безоговорочной теории русского языка" создан. Однако из текста в настоящее время изъято несколько весьма важных авторских купюр, которые пока ещё находятся в статусе не публикуемой интеллектуальной собственности.

Объясняется это тем, что данная теория предложена на рассмотрение Президента Беларуси А.Г. Лукашенко для того, чтобы её использовать в качестве научной парадигмы. Кроме того, текст теории разослан в ознакомительных целях нескольким уважаемым лицам России - список прилагается. Это на тот случай, чтобы потом никто не мог сказать, что такого текста не было. Надеюсь, если у кого пробудится интерес по данной проблеме, обращайтесь к ним.

К своему разъяснению прилагаю текст ссылки с адресами, у кого можно попросить сам текст теории:

"Открытое обращение к активистам развития научных представлений о русском языке и русской истории от гражданина России Стрельцова И.А."

http://www.litsovet.ru/index.php/material.read?material_id=434264

Comment: Первый раз слышу, что Лукашенко - специалист в области языкознания.

Comment: Да. Второй после Виссарионыча.

Comment: Чистая самореклама.

Comment: Заявление.
    
Уважаемый Александр Григорьевич! 
   
Я  обращаюсь к Вам, Президенту дружественной страны и прошу Вас рассмотреть в особом порядке и принять соответствующие распоряжения относительно определения дальнейшей конкретной  судьбы моего научно-критического исследования под названием «Безоговорочная теория русского языка», насколько это будет позволительно  в рамках существующей юрисдикции Республики Беларусь. 
Помогите мне сейчас, чтобы я очень быстро и продуктивно смог помочь Вам вскоре, именно как последней опоре и надежде   Русской цивилизации, ибо это действительно так.

Comment: Паранойяльный синдром — наиболее лёгкая форма бредового синдрома, более лёгкая, чем параноид.  Помимо указанных бредовых идей реже встречается монотематический бред реформаторства, эротический, высокого происхождения, сутяжный (кверулянтский).

Хронический паранойяльный синдром характеризуется последовательным развитием фабулы бреда, его расширением, систематизацией и нередко ярко выраженной детализацией и “кривой логикой”. Развернутый синдром сочетается с повышенной активностью (открытой борьбой за свои идеи) и лёгкими аффективными расстройствами... (с) Википедия

Answer (score 3):

А Бараку Обаме отослали?

Я, кстати, уже предупреждал Вас, что мелко плаваете. 
Я бы на Вашем месте не мелочился и создал окончательную "Общую теорию всего".

Comment: не, начинать надо с всеобщей теории поля. А уж потом - всего.

Comment: В виду того, что отсутствие личного опыта делает недоступным восприятию все, что может касаться этого, наивный в чем-то человек принципиально не может видеть свои ошибки в предположениях или оценить понимание другого в этом отношении. Даже если будет сделана попытка объяснить ему, наивный не готов еще понять это, оставаясь при той уверенности, которая у него уже есть. Он просто уверен, что это не он, а другой (более опытный на самом деле) ошибается в предположениях.

Comment: >В виду того, что отсутствие личного опыта делает недоступным восприятию все  

Простите, не надо быть курицей, чтобы отличить тухлое яйцо.

Comment: Все-таки почитала текст пр ссылке. Вспомнился трактат "О введении единомыслияв России". Эх, ничто не ново подлуной!

Answer (score 1):

Я не возражаю, чтобы Иван Стрельцов стал миллионером.

Comment: Ну что ж, бросьте тогда первым в Ивана Стрельцова подходящей купюрой!

Answer (score 0):

> Однако из текста в настоящее время
> изъято несколько весьма важных
> авторских купюр

Спасибо! давно меня так никто не радовал. Вы не печатались раньше под псевдонимом Козьма Прутков?

Comment: Иногда именно работы дилетантов  дают
 понятие о ничтожестве академической науки. Ж. Ростан

Comment: Иногда. ..